# JUNG graphs: vertex similarity?

Tags: similarity, jung, vertices

I have a **JUNG graph** containing about 10K vertices and 100K edges, and I'd like to get a measure of similarity between any pair of vertices.
The vertices represent concepts (e.g. dog, house, etc), and the links represent relations between concepts (e.g. related, is_a, is_part_of, etc).

The vertices are densely inter-linked, so a shortest-path approach doesn't give good results (the shortest paths are always very short).

What approaches would you recommend to rank the connectivity between vertices?

JUNG has [some algorithms](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/apidocs/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/scoring/package-summary.html) to score the importance of vertices, but I don't understand if there are measures of similarity between 2 vertices.
[SimPack](http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/ddis/research/simpack/) seems also promising.

Any hints?

Comment: Mulone: The question of what sorts of approaches are appropriate depends on the semantics of the vertices, the edges, and whether you have any other attributes for either one. There isn't really a one-size-fits-all answer to this question. If you can provide more information, I can try to give you a more useful answer. :)

Comment: Ron's answer is good in general.  However, "similarity" on a graph defined such as you describe is not well-defined.  "is_a, is_part_of, related" and such can certainly induce subgraphs (e.g., include everything that one can reach from vertex V by following "is_a" links) which are basically equivalence classes, or variations on same.  But it's not clear how to get similarity out of this.  (If you can reach B from A with 4 "related" links, is that a stronger or a weaker connection than 3 "is_part_of" links?)  What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `centrality` scores don't measure similarity of pairs of vertices, but some kind of (depending on the method) centrality of single nodes of the network in general. Therefore this approach is possibly not what you want.

`SimPack` indeed has a nice goal set out, but for graphs it implements isomorphism-based comparations, which rather compare multiple graphs for similarity than pairs of nodes of one given graph. Therefore this is out of scope for now.

What you are seeking are so-called `graph clustering` methods (also called network module determination or network community determination methods), which divide the graph (network) into multiple partitions so that the **nodes in each partition are more strongly interconnected with each other than with nodes of other partitions**.

The most classic method is maybe the betweenness centrality clustering of Newman & Girvan where you can exploit the [dendrogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) for similarity calculation, and it [is in JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/EdgeBetweennessClusterer.html). Of course there are throngs of methods nowadays. You may want to try (shameless plug) our [ModuLand method](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0012528), or read the fine table of module detection algorithms at the end of the [Electronic Supplementary Material](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0012528#pone.0012528.s001). That is an `overlapping graph clustering` method family, that is its result for each node is a vector containing the strengths of belonging to any respective cluster of the network. Pairwise node similarity is easy to derive from pairs of these node-to-cluster vectors.

Graph clustering is non-trivial, and possible you would need to adapt any method for very precise domain-specific results, but that's up to the reader ;) Good luck!

Comment: By the way, you seem to have information from some ontology, which tend to contain large tree-like directed subgraphs (the is-a, is-part-of relations) if you don't count the 'related' links. You may be able to work out a decent similarity measure based on the ontology tree, and may augment it based on the graph clustering based similarity.

Comment: Also, if you can transform the nodes to vectors any way, then you can get the similarity as described above. The simplest (but not too sophisticated method) would be to define the vector for a node as the shortest distance to all the other nodes of the network.